# Filtering in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to use filter for the more than one field of an array. As of now I could able to filter for any record or single record. But I wanted it to be for specified record. For example some my array contains fields like firstName, lastName, phoneNo,age. I want to filter the result for firstname and lastname throught input. Here is the code for single record field filter. I want it for two/more but not all record field filter.

here I want to use search.fname and search.lname in input field but its not working. I think we cannt use two ng-model in the same tag.

Comment: Didn't you missed the example?

Answer (score 1):

The [filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter) API page has an example where two textboxes (ng-models search.name and search.phone) are used to filter the single friends list:

```
<tr ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:search">
```

Whatever content is in the "name" textbox will be used to filter the friends array against the name properties within each object of that array.

Whatever content is in the "phone" textbox will also be used to filter the friends array against the phone properties within each object of that array.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this example makes things clear for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/ed9A2/1/

Interesting section, note how you can choose field to filter by and ng-model variable

```
<tr ng-repeat="player in playersFound = (players | filter:{id: player_id, name:player_name, age:player_age})">
```